# Structures and constant structures

Tags: c, struct, constants, typedef

I have a structure in C which represents a range of integers:

```
typedef struct {
    int* data;
    unsigned start;
    unsigned end;
} Range;
```

I have one function which writes values to a range

```
bool range_put(Range* const r, int value, unsigned idx)
{
    if(r->start <= idx && idx < r->end)
    {
        r->data[idx] = value;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and one function which reads from a range

```
bool range_get(const Range* const r, int* const out, unsigned idx)
{
    if(r->start <= idx && idx < r->end)
    {
        *out = r->data[idx];
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is extend these functions so that I can have a Range to const integers. Something along the lines of

```
typedef struct {
    const int* data;
    unsigned start;
    unsigned end;
} ConstRange;
```

How can I make `range_get()` operate on both `Range` and `ConstRange`?

One solution would be to simply duplicate the functionality of `range_get()` into a new function `bool crange_get(const ConstRange*...)` but I would like to keep the number of functions low.

Another solution would be to unionize `Range` (dubious whether or not this is "allowed")

```
typedef union {
    ConstRange const_range;
    struct {
        int* data;
        unsigned start;
        unsigned end;
    }
} Range;
```

The downside here is that the syntax for calling `range_get()` gets a little more complicated when passing in a `Range`

```
Range range;
...
range_get(&range.const_range ...);
```

What are other alternatives keeping number of functions and complexity in using the functions down?

```
Range range;
ConstRange const_range;
...
range_get(&range ...);
range_get(&const_range ...);
```

Comment: You do know that once you have a `const int *` that is pointing to some memory, then you can't change or even *initialize* the memory through your pointer. If you use e.g. `malloc` to allocate the memory, then you will be stuck with uninitialized memory for the lifetime of it. A solution might be to keep track of which elements in the range that have been written to *once*, anbd not allow them to be written to again. This can be accomplished with an array of flags, one flag for each element in the range. As for the const/non-const part, a simple boolean flag should suffice.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "... then you can't change ..." - You **shall not**. `const` is a guarantee given by the programmer, not enforced by the compiler. It just allows the compiler to warn the user, but does not to keep him from shooting in his foot.

Comment: You could us a `union` with the two values. Use the `const int *` for all but modification functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with a large number of functions.  The only (potential) problem is code duplication.  So, write not one, but *two* more functions:

Write a new function `bool range_get2(const int* data, unsigned start, unsigned end, const r, int* const out, unsigned idx)`

Then make your existing `bool range_get(const Range* const r, int* const out, unsigned idx)` work by delegating to `range_get2()`.  Note that `range_get2()` will accept either a `const int* data` or an `int* data`; it does not mind.

Then introduce your new `bool crange_get(const ConstRange*...)` and make it *also* work by delegating to `range_get2()`.

Thus, you may have more functions, but at least you will not have code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make range_get() operate on both Range and ConstRange?

**TL;DR**: you can't, at least not directly.

`const`-qualified types are not "compatible" with non-`const`-qualified types.  Thus `int` and `const int` are not compatible.  It does make a difference for some purposes, however, that the latter is a qualifed version of the former.

Two pointer types referring to incompatible types are not compatible with each other, so `int *` and `const int *` are not compatible.  Nor, in this case, is one a `const`-qualified version of the other.

Structure types with different tags or whose correspondingly-named members do not have compatible types are not compatible with each other, either, so your `Range` and `ConstRange` are not compatible.

You cannot, therefore, write a conforming program that accesses an object of type `ConstRange` as if it were of type `Range`, or *vise versa*.  It is forbidden by C2011, 6.5/7 (the "strict aliasing rule").  Indeed, it is not even required that the representations of these two structure types be laid out correspondingly (though in practice, they almost surely will be).

Nor can you access an object of type `int *` as if it were of type `const int *`, or *vise versa*, though you can *convert* a value of one of those pointer types to the other type.  Behavior of such a conversion is well-defined in every case as long as the new type does not have a larger alignment requirement than the old, which would be very surprising here.  And such a conversion could be useful, because you are permitted to access an `int` as a `const int` -- by dereferencing a `const int *` obtained by conversion from an `int *`, for example.

Thus, you can write conforming helper functions that serve as a common back end for reading (but not modifying) the `data` members of `ConstRange` and `Range` objects, as @MikeNakis suggested, but you cannot write a conforming function that accepts a parameter of one of those types and in any way accommodates the corresponding argument being of the other type.

The closest you could come would be to use a union, but not quite the way you present.  Use of a union still does not permit a `Range` to be accessed as if it were a `ConstRange`, and no amount of gymnastics around footnote 95 gets around the fact that these two are not required to be laid out correspondingly, and that their `data` members do not have corresponding type.  *In practice*, such machinations very likely produce the expected result, but a program employing them is nevertheless non-conforming and relies on undefined behavior.

There is, however, a variety of union-based approaches that do work, being based on providing a way to set and later recall which union member is the active one.  Consider:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        int *data;
        const int *cdata;
    };
    unsigned start;
    unsigned end;
    _Bool is_const;
} Range;

_Bool range_get(const Range* const r, int * const out, unsigned idx) {
    if (r->start <= idx && idx < r->end) {
        const int *data = r->is_const ? r->cdata : r->data;

        *out = data[idx];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you insist on having a completely separate type for ranges of constant integers then you can still do something similar.  The key is that you need a means to tell the function which member of the union to access.

Comment: Note, by the way, that I have copied your style by making the `r` and `out` parameters to `range_get` be `const`, but this does not serve any useful purpose (as opposed to `r` also being a pointer to a `const` object, which *does* serve a purpose).